# Now in UNIX time

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have changed the date field I am using in one of my sites. The new field appears to store the dates in UNIX time format.

I was using this:

```
AND matrix.col_id_3 > (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d'))
```

to check if the date stored in matrix.col_id_3 was more than todays date.

How can I do this with the UNIX time format?

The dates look like this: 1412736180

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(matrix.col_id_r),'%Y%m%d') > DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `AND matrix.col_id_r > NOW()` or  `AND DATE_FORMAT(matrix.col_id_3, '%Y%m%d') > DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d')`